# Maximum x dimension of the grid is too low

Tags: cuda

deviceQuery tool gives me this information among other things:

```
CUDA Driver Version / Runtime Version          9.1 / 8.0
CUDA Capability Major/Minor version number:    5.0
Max dimension size of a grid size    (x,y,z): (2147483647, 65535, 65535)
```

When I create the default CUDA 8.0 project in Visual Studio 2015 and change kernel call from:

```
addKernel<<<1, size>>>(dev_c, dev_a, dev_b);
```

to

```
addKernel<<<dim3(65535, 1, 1), size>>>(dev_c, dev_a, dev_b);
```

it still works. But when change the x-dimension of the grid to 65536 like this:

```
addKernel<<<dim3(65536, 1, 1), size>>>(dev_c, dev_a, dev_b);
```

I get `cudaErrorInvalidValue (11)` which means "invalid argument". Why?

(I have only one CUDA-capable device on the machine, so I'm not confusing it with some other one)

Comment: because you are using CUDA 8.0 which has a default compile target of cc2.0 which only supports a maximum of 65535.  If you want to take advantage of the higher maximum available with your device, you need to modify the GPU target settings in your VS project to match the compute capability of your device (cc5.0).

Comment: @RobertCrovella That's exactly the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that by default Visual Studio sets the build flags to compute capability `2.0`.

To change them:

1. Open the project's Properties page
2. Under `CUDA C/C++` select `Device` tab
3. Change `Code Generation` value from `compute_20,sm_20` to whatever your graphic card supports. In my case it's `compute_50,sm_50`.